# Как сделать php скрипт чтобы он был всегда запущен и ожидал get запросы

Tags: php, ubuntu, ispmanager

Я не понимаю как мне создать скрипт php, который будет запускаться 1 раз и потом только ожидать запросы, без повторных запусков.

Мне требуется чтобы при запуске он запускал мою функцию инициализации, а потом принимал get запросы не останавливаясь или хотя бы не повторяя инициализацию

Comment: запросы не скрипт принимает, а вэб-сервер. Что там у вас в инициализации этой, что вам так важно ее не повторять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял автора, вам нужно, чтобы был запущен какой-то PHP-скрипт, который бы обрабатывал HTTP-запросы, не завершая процесс. В таком случае вам придётся написать PHP-скрипт, который будет запускаться в CLI со связкой с остальным веб-приложением через сокеты, либо написать полноценное PHP-приложение, которое будет запускать свой веб-сервер